# How to write onclick llistener for notification item in android?

Tags: android

Hi i am new to android. 
I am implementing a code with notification functionality. Here i have two activities in my application those are ActivityA, and ActivityB.
I want to start ActivityB from notification and i need to send some flag or some value to the ActivityB. How can i send the data like int value or flag to that called activity using notification on click. The problem is when i am launching activity from launcher icon first it will called ActivityA and from that ActivityA i am passing some value to ActivityB.
But when i am launching ActivityB from notification i con't send any values to that activity so it is giving force close.

To call activity from notification i am using this code

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
final Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.android,"New Alert, Click Me!",System.currentTimeMillis());
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "Notification Details...";
CharSequence contentText = "Browse Android Official Site by clicking me";               
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notifyIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("mypackage","mypackage.ActivityB"));

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, 0,notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);
mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, notifyDetails);
```

Please advise me how can i send values from notification to called activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must set your ActivityB in notifyIntent

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class); // 'this' - Context object
```

For sending values use extras
for example:

```
intent.putExtra("yourTag", yourVariable);
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. Can i get the passed value as getIntent.getExtras(); method?